Could Butch Wilmore use BEAM as sleeping quarters?
According to Business Insider, while Sunita Williams is using (sharing?) a sleep module during her stay on the ISS, Butch Wilmore is 'roughing it' in a science module.  I've seen comments that he has to pack his stuff away during the day to make the JAXA Kibo module available for science stuff.

According to NASA, the ISS only has six private sleeping quarters.
Time reported that each quarter has a sleeping bag, a storage area for
snacks and personal belongings, and two laptops attached to the walls.
But Wilmore and Williams joined an international crew of seven people
already at the ISS — so the sleep cabins were already at maximum
capacity.
Time reported that Williams camps with one of the astronauts in a
basic sleep module called the CASA, or Crew Alternate Sleep
Accommodation.
And Wilmore has been given a sleeping bag to rest in, out in the
Japanese module.

It occurred to me that there's probably room in BEAM, the inflatable module that arrived at the ISS in 2016 for a temporary visit but was so useful it has become a permanent attachment.
BEAM is currently being used for storage, this image shows the module with storage bins installed but the remaining space looks to be about the size of an ISS sleep module:

Obviously, people would need access to the items stored there from time-to-time, and I imagine ventilation and airflow would need to be checked since it is a dead-end unit not intended for habitation, but could BEAM be used as a temporary sleeping module rather than taking up space in a module that is in daily use?

About a year ago it looked more like this https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/iss070e000324/iss070e000324~orig.jpg but I don't know about currently.

You room is in the storage closet, but right now we're storing our supplies there, so.... have fun!

As of this 2022 video, there's now a 7th sleep station in Columbus (which appears to be of a different design). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyFHsvHR47Q

Steam Pipe Trunk Distribution Venue
